# segmentation fault while using Net::ssh::perl module with threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, ssh

After running this program

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Code below:

```
use threads;
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $host = 'hostname';
my $user = 'root';
my $password = 'root123';

my $thread = threads->new (\&ThreadEntry,"ls");
my $thread1 = threads->new (\&ThreadEntry,"ls -al ");

sub ThreadEntry()
{
    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, 35903);
    print "in ssh function \n";
    my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) =$ssh->cmd(@_);
    print "$stdout $stderr $exit\n";
}

$thread->join();
$thread1->join();
```

Comment: Please add more information to this question - like what the program is supposed to do etc. otherwise there's a very real risk this will be closed.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, see link below:
https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=62053